# NHibernate: why ILifecycle.OnUpdate is not called every time?

Tags: nhibernate, lifecycle, onupdate

NHibernate_reference.pdf, page 26:

> Note that ILifecycle.OnUpdate() is not called every time the object's persistent state is updated. It is called only when a
>   transient object is passed to ISession.Update().

Why it design link that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ILifecycle is deprecated; as James L wrote, you should use an IInterceptor implementation instead. My interpretation of the documentation you quoted is that the OnUpdated event is fired from the Update method only. That is, the event was designed to notify subscribers that the Update method had been called and nothing more.

Answer (score 2):

You should use IInterceptor instead